# Retrieve properties from List(T), any options besides FOR EACH

Tags: .net, linq, list

I know that I can use FOR EACH to easily accomplish my goal below, however I run into this scenario a LOT and was wondering if there was a more elegant solution.

```
Class Foo
    Public X as String
    Public Y as Integer   
End Class

Dim c As New List(Of Foo) = GetFooItemsFromDatabase......
```

I want to get a comma delimited string of all the X's in c.  If I had a simple array of string called simpleArray I could do something like

```
dim s as String = String.Join(", ", simpleArray)
```

Is there a way of building simpleArray (LINQ, built in functions, etc) that will accomplish this instead of having to use FOR EACH and build it myself?

EDIT: It seems LINQ is the way to go.  However converting the many suggestions from C# to VB yields the following which the compiler does not like.

```
Dim s As String = c.[Select](Function(myVal) myValue.X)
```

Comment: `foreach` _is_ pretty concise, but, each to their own.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment Well yeah, but, it's so 1.0... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK this is C#, so apologies, but you could use a little LINQ:

```
string.Join(", ", c.Select(c => c.X).ToArray());
```

The `Select` extension method allows you to project the output, you are basically taking an enumerable of `c` and projecting it to an enumerable of `X`. You then call `ToArray` to translate your `IEnumerable<string>` into a `string[]` (in C# vernacular).

LINQ is fully supported in VB.NET and is well worth reading more into:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763068.aspx

If you are new to it, the standard naming of "LINQ" tends to cover both the new syntax:

```
from name in names 
select name
```

And also its guise in extension methods:

```
.Select().Where().OrderBy(); //.etc()
```

A VB.NET LINQ source:

http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/Section/LINQ-Extension-Methods-with-Visual-Basic-2008.id-310907.html

Comment: I'm new to LINQ and have been playing with it for about a week now, however I'm really confused by the Extension Method and can't find any VB examples or documentation.  Have you any suggestions?

Comment: @WhiskerBiscuit You're right, it seems a little difficult to search for. I found one link that appeared to talk about the relevant stuff, lots of other links are just examples of Extension Methods in VB.NET, not LINQ-specific.

Answer (score 1):

Using C# and .NET 4.0,

```
string s = string.Join(", ", c.Select(x => x.X));
```

and the same code as VB.NET

```
Dim s As String = String.Join(", ", c.[Select](Function(x) x.X))
```

With .NET 4, you don't need to call `ToArray()` anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
var s = String.Join(", ", c.Select(foo => foo.X));
```

Or alternatively you can use this:

```
var s = c.Select (foo => foo.X).Aggregate((p, c) => p + ", " + c);
```

Answer (score 1):

can't you just do:

```
String.Join(",", c.Select(item=>item.X).ToArray())
```

Comment: Dim s As String = c.[Select](Function(x) x.X)  is giving the compiler fits for some reason

Comment: right.. because it's not a string-- that's going to be an IEnumerable<string>... no?